# Show div according to the clicked link attr jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, href, show

For 2 hours now I'm struggling with this problem. What I need is that when one of the links is clicked, jQuery should show the div that has the same ID as the `href` attribute.

If for example I click on the first link (`href="#form1"`) it must show the `<div>` with the ID *#form1*

```
<script>

$(".nav a").click(function(){

    var attr = $(this).attr("href");
    var $form = $(".form"); 

    if ("#" + $form.attr("id") == attr) {
        $(attr).addClass("active");
        $container.isotope('layout');
    } else {
        $form.removeClass("active");
        $container.isotope('layout'); 
    }

});

</script>

<div class="form" id="form1"></div>
<div class="form" id="form2"></div>
<div class="form" id="form3"></div>

<div class="nav">
     <a href="#form1">click to see #form1</a>
     <a href="#form2">click to see #form2</a>
     <a href="#form3">click to see #form3</a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this code block:

```
if ("#" + $form.attr("id") == attr) {
    $(attr).addClass("active");
    $container.isotope('layout');
} else {
    $form.removeClass("active");
    $container.isotope('layout'); 
}
```

to this:

```
$form.removeClass("active");
$(attr).addClass("active");
$container.isotope('layout');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3gkAV/)**

Your if condition won't work, but that's irrelevant anyway since you don't even need an if. When you click a link, just remove the class from all the divs and add it to the one you need via the href attribute you're grabbing with `$form.removeClass("active");`. Note that you may want to also prevent the page jump associated with clicking on bookmark anchors by adding `preventDefault()` to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop your `.form` ;)

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(".nav a").click(function() {
    $(".form").removeClass("active");

    var id = this.href;
    $(id).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
$(".nav a").click(function(){

    // At first remove the class called active from all the 
    // elements that have as a class the form
    $(".form").removeClass("active");

    // Get the href attribute's value of the clicked anchor.
    var formId = $(this).attr("href");

    // add the class active to the selected form.
    $(formId).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code:

```
$(".nav a").click(function(){
    var attr = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".form").each(function(){
        if ("#" + $(this).attr("id") == attr) {
            $(attr).addClass("active");
            $container.isotope('layout');
        } else {
             $form.removeClass("active");
             $container.isotope('layout'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
$(".nav a").click(function(){

      var attr = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");;
      $('.form').removeClass("active");
      $('.form[id=' + attr ']').addClass("active");
});
```

first get the href value without `#`. Then remove `active` class from all `.form` elements.
Finally get the `.form` with the `id` equal `attr` variable and give it `active` class.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share a different answer/approach (shorter code) to this question.

**jQuery:**

```
$(".nav a").click(function(){

   var attr = $(this).attr("href");
   $(attr).show();
   $(attr).siblings(".form").hide();


});
```

**DEMO HERE:** http://jsfiddle.net/8u7n2/

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this one..  

  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>

      <body>
    <div class="form" id="form1">ABC</div>
    <div class="form" id="form2">XYZ</div>
    <div class="form" id="form3">PQR</div>

    <div class="nav">
         <a href="#form1">click to see #form1</a>
         <a href="#form2">click to see #form2</a>
         <a href="#form3">click to see #form3</a>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav a").click(function(){
        $(".form").removeClass("active");
        var attr = $(this).attr("href");
        $(attr) .addClass("active");

    });
    });

    </script>
    <style>
    .active
    {
      background-color: red;
    }

      </style>
      </body>

    </html>
```

[see this](http://plnkr.co/edit/z7VhAKIXWgxOBF5ZZ9xV?p=preview)